# Apache's sudden drop of requests

Tags: apache-httpd, performance

My server was working fine until a couple of weeks ago. All of a sudden, I started getting error notices from PHP.

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0

At first, I thought it was a MySQL issue, but after further investigation I've noticed a sudden drop of Apache requests accompanied by a small peak of the "Sending reply" state. It happens once or twice a day unpredictably, and it's very fast. It takes maybe 1 or 2 seconds. I've seen other similar topics here, but on those people report slowness for minutes or hours. That's not my case. By the time I'm aware of what happened, it's already gone. The peak below is the only abnormality I could find. Apart from that, all other graphs are normal. Any guesses?

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 .

[image: Scoreboard]